# full calendar plugin -issue with the overlay in weekview and dayview

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, fullcalendar

The title more or less describes the nature of the problem.The problem appears only in weekview and dayview.Here is an image of the weekview:

[image: weekview problem]

As I note in the image the cancel(it is in Greek) and OK button cannot be clicked 
cause the overlay sits on top of the dialog box.
I cannot understand why this happens. I must stress that the dialog box is produced by jquery-UI and I am following this tutorial here to build an events calendar 
[tutorial](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/)

I have made some adjustments to the contents of the dialog box to fit my needs.
Lastly as I say above monthview is OK.
As you see the text is in Greek...The dialog has inputs for name,time of the day selected,duration.

Comment: could be just a zindex issue, try to check using developer tool

Comment: Where do you have the div that will wrap the dialog ? Is it inside calendar div or outside? I have outside and it works fine.

Comment: @HenriqueC....Hmmm.It is placed outside the calendar.I managed to fix the issue by adjusting the z-index values but according to you there should not be problem either way. I do not know why I am having/had this overlay issues.